# bind Azure Active Directory user to existing user in asp.net application database

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-identity

I'm working on asp.net application that uses forms authentication and asp.net Identity. Now,it is also possible to connect by Azure Directory. When a user connects through AD, he is redirected to the application and the only information I have it's email address (his microsoft account).

I tried to get userId, username but they are still null.

I tried:

```
var UserManager = new UserManager();
UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.GetEmail());
UserManager.GetClaims(User.Identity.GetUserId());
UserManager.GetEmail(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

But, user.identity doesn,t have a definition for GetEmail().

So, I would like to know how to bind this user(connected  through AD) to his information contained in the applcation's database.
Need help please.

Comment: Why don't you add a new field to extend your Asp.Net Identity table and use it to link it to the user from AD?

Comment: What will be stored in this field please?

Comment: Well, you can store the user name as in the Active Directory.  It is unique, and you can use it to locate the user by it.

Comment: The problem is that the username are stored in the sql database of the asp application and not in AD

Comment: Well, the AD does have a login name!

Comment: The username is the email address in AD. I wanted to do `UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.GetUserName())` . The problem is that on the asp application side the username is a unique id. So the code would work on the ASP side and not on the AD side.